# how to get youtube campaigns analytic using adwords account api?

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to find campaign performance parameters of campaign impression,clicks,cpc,...etc using adwords API?
How can i get these parameters programatically?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried before asking this question?

Comment: yes @VedPrakash i have refer documentation of adwords api, i have created test account and manager account also have developer keys.

Answer (score 0):

The required information is available in the [Video Performance Report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/video-performance-report).